# Cannot open flag dialog, incorrect error message after casting final close vote on question

Tags: bug, flags, vote-to-close, error-message

After I cast the final close vote against a question, if I attempt to flag it, the flag dialog refuses to open, and gives me an incorrect error message:

> This question has been put on-hold since you loaded the page - please refresh and try your action again.

As the message says, refreshing the page clears the error. However, after I cast the final close vote, the page **already** refreshes to reflect my vote and the closure, so the error message is incorrect.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a question with four close votes.
2. Cast the final close vote. The page should load and show that the question has been closed.
3. Click the "flag" button. You get the above error message.

The point of that error check is to make sure that the flag dialog doesn't get loaded if the question is closed, but doesn't show as closed in the browser since the page was loaded prior to said closure. However, upon casting the final close vote, the page reloads *immediately* to reflect the closure; the error message makes no sense since the question *does* show as closed, yet I still get it.

Reproduced in Microsoft Edge. (I have a slight feeling that this is a client-side issue; I haven't tested in other browsers.)